# Reference error "object property is not defined"

Tags: javascript, reference, defined

I have the following structure:

```
appInterface = { 
  mainWinCanvas: document.getElementById("mainwindow"),
  mainWinContext: mainWinCanvas.getContext("2d"),
  mainWinCanvasWidth: mainWinCanvas.width,
  mainWinCanvasHeight: mainWinCanvas.height, 
  mainWinCanvasData: mainWinContext.getImageData(0, 0, mainWinCanvasWidth, mainWinCanvasHeight)
}
```

and get this error in Firebug:
`mainWinCanvas is not defined`

What's causing it? I'm sure the script is called AFTER body element previous children are fully loaded.
My goal is to make the code more readable, it's no-object version is working :(

Comment: So, what to do? Seems first commenter wiped the suggestion ...

Comment: Just replace the property name with `document.getElementById("mainwindow")`(can be also cached outside of object literal), or use a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters), or create the object using constructor function.

Comment: Yeah, but this adds too much letters to the code. The second idea is cool, but this means no well structured objects. The third seems will add more code.

Comment: Actually my first suggestion is not a good option at all, but what's wrong with getters? How they mess up the structure of an object?

Comment: From MDN getter returns:
`get b() {return this.a + 1;}`
Is it allowed to `set b() { b = something(); },` ?

Comment: Yes, it's allowed, though only one argument can be passed to setter. You can pass multiple values within an array or object ofcourse.

Comment: Hmmh, is the argument required for setter? Firebug tells me it is ...

Comment: How would you set a value to a property without a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not much more coding, when creating an object with a constructor function:

```
function AppInterface (cnvid) { 
    this.mainWinCanvas = document.getElementById(cnvid);
    this.mainWinContext = this.mainWinCanvas.getContext("2d");
    this.mainWinCanvasWidth = this.mainWinCanvas.width;
    this.mainWinCanvasHeight = this.mainWinCanvas.height;
    this.mainWinCanvasData = this.mainWinContext.getImageData(0, 0, this.mainWinCanvasWidth, this.mainWinCanvasHeight);
}
var appInterface = new AppInterface("mainwindow");
```

You can even reuse the constructor, if you'd need more than one "appInterFace" in your app.

Comment: For the moment your answer is the clearest solution.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is wrap this in a function and return it as object so the `this` context should be available to your current `appInterface` Object. Also convert your properties to methods, so you can able to do method chaining.

```
var appInterface = function () {
    return {
        canvas: null,
        ctx: null,
        mainWinCanvas: function (elem) {
            if (this.canvas === null) {
                this.canvas = document.getElementById(elem);
            }
            return this;
        },
        mainWinContext: function () {
            this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
            return this;
        },
        mainWinCanvasWidth: function () {
            return this.canvas.width;
        },
        mainWinCanvasHeight: function () {
            return this.canvas.height;
        },
        mainWinCanvasData: function () {
            this.ctx.getImageData(0, 0, this.mainWinCanvasWidth(), this.mainWinCanvasHeight());
            return this;
        }
    };
};
```

Usage:

```
appInterface().mainWinCanvas('mainWindow').mainWinContext().mainWinCanvasWidth();
```

Comment: This drops another `TypeError: appInterface.CPanel is undefined` while trying to add at `document.body.onload` `appInterface.CPanel.addEventListener('click', function(){});`

Comment: @Teemu This was not i was trying to post it was posted too earlier. By the way i forgot to convert properties into methods. Now it should work.

Comment: @RahilWazir Now your code is supposed to work. I didn't downvote, so I can't remove it either...

Answer (score 0):

The object has no local context, you need to acces by its main reference `appInterface`

```
appInterface = { 
  mainWinCanvas: document.getElementById("mainwindow"),
  mainWinContext: appInterface.mainWinCanvas.getContext("2d"),
  mainWinCanvasWidth: appInterface.mainWinCanvas.width,
  mainWinCanvasHeight: appInterface.mainWinCanvas.height, 
  mainWinCanvasData: appInterface.mainWinContext.getImageData(0, 0, appInterface.mainWinCanvasWidth, appInterface.mainWinCanvasHeight)
}
```

If you want to have local context use functions instead

**EDIT**

use function constructor instead, you need a live instance for self referencing

```
var appInterface = new function(){
    this.test = 4;
};
appInterface = {
    anotherTest:appInterface.test
}

console.log(appInterface.test)
```

Comment: Have you tested this? Got `appInterface is undefined`

Comment: True, then with object is a no go, should be a function

Comment: For the `mainWinContext` I get `TypeError: appInterface is undefined`

Answer (score 0):

One lame workaround to escape writting functions and getters/setters is to do the following:

```
appInterface = new Object();
appInerface.mainWinCanvas = document.getElementById("mainwindow");
appInerface.mainWinContext = appInerface.mainWinCanvas.getContext("2d");
...
```

This is stupid, i'm not deeply in JS but don't see the difference between new Object() and corresponging defining of its properties, or structure in the question ...