# Passing a key inside a key in an object

Tags: javascript

If you run this code you'll notice that you get this error:

> error: Uncaught ReferenceError: times is not defined

I know where the problem resided, however I can't understand why I can't assign a key within a key in the object named stats. The problem resides on the 5th line in the code below. Removing that part removes the problem. Any advice? I want to be able to just multiply stats.times with 2 to get the total amount of time totally.

```js
'use strict'

var stats = {
  times: 0,
  totalTime: times * 2
}

var timer = {
  currentTime: 2,
  defaultTime: 2,
  state: "paused",
  running() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (timer.state === "running") {
        if (timer.currentTime > 0) {
          console.log(timer.currentTime);
          timer.currentTime--;
          timer.running();
        } else if (timer.currentTime === 0) {
          stats.times++;
          console.log("Timers completed: " + stats.times);
          console.log("Time total: " + stats.totalTime);
        }
      }
    }, 1000);
  },

  startpause() {
    if (timer.state === "paused") {
      timer.state = "running";
      timer.running();
    } else if (timer.state === "running") {
      if (timer.currentTime === 0) {
        timer.restart();
      } else {
        timer.state = "paused";
      }
    }
  },

  restart() {
    timer.state = "paused";
    timer.currentTime = timer.defaultTime;
  }
}

timer.startpause();
```

Comment: `totalTime: times * 2` what do you expect to happen??

Comment: Looks like `totalTime` should be a function or a getter.

Comment: I expect totalTime to equal times multiplied by 2

Comment: @Titus I was looking at a getter, would that be the way to go?

Comment: @Titus, nvm, solved

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference error "object property is not defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21812245/reference-error-object-property-is-not-defined)

Comment: What's the point of this? How is `times * 2` the total times?

Comment: @mbojko He's not referencing it as a property, just an ordinary variable.

Comment: @Barmar Total number of times the timer has been "played" multiplied by the default Time for the timer. Timer runs 10 times, 2 seconds each time, total time is 20 seconds.

Comment: But if you change `defaultTime`, `totalTime` will be wrong. Why not just print `stats.times * defaultTime`?

Comment: @Barmar True, that is a better way to go about it, I didn't think about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do times * 2 before times itself is created basically.
Since both parameters resides on the same object they are created at the same time.

If you want something more dynamic that allows you to edit times and automatically change the total time you could go with:

```
var stats = {
 times: 0,
 get totalTime() {
    return this.times * 2
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a getter, so that accessing `stats.totalTime()` will run a function to calculate the result.

```js
'use strict'

var stats = {
  times: 0,
  get totalTime() {
    return this.times * 2;
  }
}

var timer = {
  currentTime: 2,
  defaultTime: 2,
  state: "paused",
  running() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (timer.state === "running") {
        if (timer.currentTime > 0) {
          console.log(timer.currentTime);
          timer.currentTime--;
          timer.running();
        } else if (timer.currentTime === 0) {
          stats.times++;
          console.log("Timers completed: " + stats.times);
          console.log("Time total: " + stats.totalTime);
        }
      }
    }, 1000);
  },

  startpause() {
    if (timer.state === "paused") {
      timer.state = "running";
      timer.running();
    } else if (timer.state === "running") {
      if (timer.currentTime === 0) {
        timer.restart();
      } else {
        timer.state = "paused";
      }
    }
  },

  restart() {
    timer.state = "paused";
    timer.currentTime = timer.defaultTime;
  }
}

timer.startpause();
```

Comment: Thanks senpai  !